# asp .net core 5 beta - can't find the default file

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to upgrade an old web app to asp .net core with razor pages.  I've decided to use .net core v5 beta.  I'm trying to verify my setup.  I'm getting a 404 error when it can't find the index.cshtml file I have setup in the pages directory.  Any ideas on how to solve this?  I have the following setup and am assuming I am doing something wrong.  Any ideas are appreciated.  TIA

Startup.cs file:
public class Startup
{
public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

        Configuration = builder.Build();
        services.AddDbContext<GolfGameContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                x =>
                {
                    x.UseNetTopologySuite();
                    x.EnableRetryOnFailure();
                }
            ));

        services.AddElmah<SqlErrorLog>(options =>
        {
            options.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        });
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<AspNetUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<GolfGameContext>();
        services.AddScoped<UserManager<AspNetUser>>();
        services.AddScoped<SignInManager<AspNetUser>>();

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Password settings
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 6;

            // Lockout settings
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

            // User settings
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;

        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            // Cookie settings
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(150);
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login"; // If the LoginPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/Login
            options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout"; // If the LogoutPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/Logout
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied"; // If the AccessDeniedPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/AccessDenied
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });

        services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {

        });


        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
        app.UseElmah();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have resolved this issue, I think.  I recreated a project with the most recent preview from this week.  I've been able to see some things.  I think my issue is due to some nested layouts.  I'm not 100% positive, but that is what I am thinking.